# textbox in jsp that allows only text ,numbers, and comma

Tags: javascript, jsp

Textbox in jsp that allows only text numbers and comma.

this is to seperate userids.

each userid has to be 8 chars in length and i need to enter multiple userids in the textbox.

eg:

**correct format is below**

asakthi1,psubhadr,tpradee4

**it should not end like**(with a comma at the end.)**(incorrect format)**

asakthi1,psubhadr,tpradee4,

this i need to do using javascript.(No Jquery please.)

am scratching my head on this..Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could attach an `onchange` event handler to the `<input type="text">` that will perform the validation using a regular expression like, for instance, this one: `^(([A-Za-z0-9]{8}),)*[A-Za-z0-9]{8}$`.

If a username is a combination of 8 letters or numbers, this expression would accept any number of usernames followed by comma, and at least one final username without a comma. Notice the `{8}` element forces a match of exactly 8 characters.

If validation fails, it's up to you how to show it to the user. This example will be showing an alert and clearing the input.

```
<input type="text" onchange="if (!validate(this.value)) { alert('incorrect value'); this.value = ''; }">

<script>
function validate​(value){
    return value.match(new RegExp("^(([A-Za-z0-9]{8}),)*[A-Za-z0-9]{8}$")) != null;
}​
</script>
```

Here is a sample [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/56LDy/1/) to see the expression at work.

Comment: Thank You Xavi..am very new to front end programming..basically a java and oracle guy..i guess you understood my problem so well..the most precise answer...i would love to give 10 upvotes..for it..